# Aurora PostgreSQL doing high amount of IO:SLRURead irrespective of the shared_buffers size

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, aws-aurora

I have a table that is about 5-6 GB in size. Whenever my application is doing SELECT queries on this table, the performance insight shows a high amount of **IO:SLRURead** wait event.

I've tried this with r6g.large and r6g.4xlarge i.e. 16GB and 128GB of memory respectively. From my understanding, the table and its indexes should fit in the shared_buffers comfortably.

What could be the reason for it?

I'm using PostgreSQL 14.3.
Since this is a production database, these queries can easily go up to 30req/sec.

Comment: Do you have transactions being held open, or perhaps prepared transactions?

Comment: Are EXPLAIN ANALYZE plans for your queries indicating a lot of sequential scans?

Comment: Here's the plan of total rows count query -https://explain.depesz.com/s/qL8b

Comment: That is an awful lot of heap fetches going on.  I would say your table is under-vacuumed and probably under-analyzed as well.

Comment: @jjanes Yes, that was the issue. I'm doing the `VACUUM FULL` weekly to alleviate this issue.